# saving cakephp date fields

Tags: php, cakephp, time, cakephp-1.3

I have a form that includes an hour and minute drop down using this: `'dateFormat'=>'NONE', 'timeFormat'=>'24'` But now when i save the form `$this->data` ends up looking like the array below and because `eventStartDate` & `eventStartDate` are arrays it makes an SQL error saying `eventStartDate` can not be null etc.

```
Array
(
    [Work] => Array
        (
            [eventStartDate] => Array
                (
                    [hour] => 12
                    [min] => 00
                )

            [eventEndDate] => Array
                (
                    [hour] => 12
                    [min] => 45
                )

            [description] => 234
            [projectID] => 7105
            [taskID] => 1
            [userid] => 8
        )

)
```

- Shouldnt cakephp make these arrays into strings so they can be put into the database automatically?
- What values for day, month etc will be used?

Comment: what type is your `eventStartDate` field in the database table?

Comment: And why aren't you specifying the day/month/year? Is that set some where else?

Comment: its `datetime` and im not specifying the rest because it needs to be the current day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might help, as it worked for me:
Your view code should look something like this

```
echo $form->dateTime('your_column_name', 'NONE', '24');
```

Comment: +1, tested+confirmed. I was going to suggest setting the `day/month/year` values in a beforeSave but this is a much nicer solution.

Comment: Thanks, I was using input(), didn't see this anywhere in the documentation!